# .NET 4 GC known thresholds to trigger collection?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, .net-4.0, clr4.0

I know that the logic for GC to trigger is not simple but it has certain thresholds to monitor.

Anyone knows what are these thresholds could be for .NET 4 workstation and server GC ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no set thresholds, they dynamically change as the garbage collector learns more about the program's allocation pattern.  There is no way for you to discover the current threshold, nor to change it.  From casual observation, it appears workstation GC starts out with a 2 megabyte gen 0 heap.  Which can grow to over 8 megabytes.

Server GC is quite different from workstation, it normally uses larger thresholds and multiple threads to collect garbage.  Again, nothing you could discover, other than by observing the performance counters in Perfmon.exe